# Why does the Web API routing engine disregard return types?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, url-routing, asp.net-web-api-routing

I was getting, "System.Net.WebException. The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error" and, after much gnashing of teeth and puckering of cheeks (I'll never tell which pair), by entering my Web API string into the browser, I found that the real problem was:

```
<Error>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
Multiple actions were found that match the request: Int32 GetCountOfDepartmentRecords() on type HandheldServer.Controllers.DepartmentsController System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[HandheldServer.Models.Department] GetAllDepartments() on type HandheldServer.Controllers.DepartmentsController
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException</ExceptionType>
</Error>
```

I saw that my controller did indeed have two parameter-less methods:

```
public int GetCountOfDepartmentRecords()
{
    return deptsRepository.Get();
}

public IEnumerable<Department> GetAllDepartments()
{
    return deptsRepository.GetAll();
}
```

...but one returns an int, and the other a generic collection; here's the Repository code:

```
public int Get()
{
    return departments.Count;
}

public IEnumerable<Department> GetAll()
{
    return departments;
}
```

...so why would the Web API routing engine be confused? Isn't it smart enough to look at the return type and select the correct method?

Anyway, I solved the problem by commenting out the GetAll() method.

Comment: What do you want it to do? Web API methods can return any data type.

Comment: c# doesn't allow methods that only differ in their return type (i.e. return type isn't part of the signature). Web api allows for multiple formatters to negotiate on the actual returned value. How should one be magically selected?

Comment: @SLaks: I want it to figure out which method to call based on its return type, not throw up its hands and claim not to be able to tell.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: "Magically selected"? I'm sure it wouldn't be an insurmountable problem for Microsoft to provide that ability. After all, they can send a man to the moon (or perform similar amazing stunts, anyway).

Comment: @ClayShannon: Yes.  All of those stunts start with a precise definition of the problem.  You still haven't suggested any reason for Web API to prefer one over the other.

Comment: Imagine that you have two methods that return `int` and `somethingElse`. Imagine, further, that the incoming request has an `Accept` header that only wants an `application/froo` response. Imagine, still further, that you have two formatters registered that claim to be able to return an `application/froo` given an `int` and an `application/froo` given a `somethingElse`. Which method should be invoked?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever and SLaks: Okay, I see your point; my bad.